# sending birthday notification in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When users register for the site i'm building, birthday notification is supposed to be sent to each user on his/her birthday. How do i go about that. Already i've created an event content type, and with help of calendar module i display user's birthday notification on my site, but cannot automatically send birthday notification to their email on their birthdays.

Comment: don't know about specificity about drupal, but a daily cron job to check for today's birthdays would be the standard approach

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Birthdays](http://drupal.org/project/birthdays) module.

> The Birthdays module allows users to add their birthday to their profile. It also lists birthdays on a seperate page and in different blocks. Users can receive an e-mail on their birthday automatically, and the administrator can receive periodic reminders of who are having their birthday. Uses Profile module from core.